# Increase row height of tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm using the `tabularx` package from within memoir for creating a table. I'm trying to set the row height and found for `tabular` the command

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{40pt}
```

However, with my `tabularx` table it doesn't seem to work and I can't find any way to do it (except maybe by manually setting each newline to a certain height)

Is there a better way to set the row height of all rows within a `tabularx`?

Comment: See [Column padding in tables](http://goo.gl/X3kPH)

Comment: Ahhhh! Come on, that was an easy one! Sorry!

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, we could close this question as a duplicate. Give some feedback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### `\extrarowheight`

The dimen register `\extrarowheight` is provided by package `array`, which is automatically loaded by package `tabularx`. Thus `\extrarowheight` works as expected in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{40pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
Hello\\
World
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### `\arraystretch`

A different method is the redefinition of the factor `\arraystretch`. It is applied to the automatic struts, inserted in the tabular, see the question ["Column padding in tables"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/16967), found by Werner.

Comment: Strangely `extrarowheight` doesn't work for me, but `arraystretch` does. Maybe interference with another package?

Comment: @navige: Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem.